# Android Matrix.multiplyMV not changing my result by the translation

Tags: android, opengl-es, matrix, 3d

I am trying to translate a set of points in one coordinate system to another coordinate system for my Android OpenGL project.

Assume `matrix` is a float array of 16 elements.
Assume `points` is a reference to an array of float arrays each with 4 elements. (`points = new float[8][4]`)

I set the matrix to an identity matrix, I then translate it and multiply by the rotation of the gameobject. I then try to translate each of the 8 vertices into the new matrices coordinates system, but none of the points are changing.

```
Matrix.setIdentityM(matrix, 0);
Matrix.translateM(matrix, 0, go.getPosition().getX(), go.getPosition().getY(), go.getPosition().getZ());
Matrix.multiplyMM(matrix, 0, matrix, 0, go.getRotationArray(), 0);      
//Matrix.rotateM(matrix, 0, 30f, 1.5f, -5f, 0f); testing debug purpose

for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
{
    Matrix.multiplyMV(points[i], 0, matrix, 0, points[i], 0);
}
```

I am basically trying to do what Android's 2D canvas and Matrix 'mapPoints' does.

Answer (score 3):

When you have a vector, your last element of the 4 long vector must be 1 and not 0! So non of the translation data was being multiplied correctly. (Well it was being done correctly, just not how I wanted it.) So when android.opengl.Matrix asks for a vector of four long and the first three elements represent your x,y,z, make sure the fourth element is set to 1!